# Grails domain class constructor with id instead of object

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

My domain class looks like this  :

```
class UserEvent { 
    User user
    Event event
    boolean isAttending
}
```

Generated database table looks has following columns:

```
[ID , EVENT_ID, USER_ID , IS_ATTENDING ]
```

I have Event object and only id of User object (user_id).
I want to create new UserEvent object with this data only, without loading User object, it may look something like this:

```
def userEvent = new UserEvent(user:['id':user_id],isAttending: true, event: event)
```

I've tried a lot of things but didn't find the solution. I think it is definitely possible, since it is done in a similar way with params in controllers which contain only ids of associated objects:

```
 def userEvent= new UserEvent(params)
```

I am looking forward to finding the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say "without loading the User object", you can do this:

```
def userEvent = new UserEvent(user:User.load(user_id), isAttending: true, event: event)
```

Unlike `get`, the [`load`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/load.html) method does not hit the database.  Instead, it creates a proxy object that only fetches its data from the database the first time a non-`id` property is accessed.